# ECharts js - Custom HTML Legend

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have created a pie chart using [ECharts](https://www.echartsjs.com/en/index.html). Thus, I would like to use a custom HTML for my legend but I don't know how to use their events.

Here is a fiddle of what I've done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/fwpzjnt7/1/

I don't know the right function/event to make my custom legend clickable so I can show/hide the selected data!

I have found some events/actions here https://www.echartsjs.com/en/api.html#events

```
dispatchAction({
    type: 'legendToggleSelect',
    // legend name
    name: string
})
```

Does anyone know how can I use actions/events to apply it to my custom html legend?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for something like the below chart where user will be able to filter chart.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
var option = {
  legend: {
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 10,
    data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  },
  series: [{
    name: '访问来源',
    type: 'pie',
    radius: ['0%', '70%'],
    avoidLabelOverlap: false,
    labelLine: {
      normal: {
        show: false
      }
    },
    data: [{
        value: 335,
        name: 'a'
      },
      {
        value: 310,
        name: 'b'
      },
      {
        value: 234,
        name: 'c'
      },
      {
        value: 135,
        name: 'd'
      },
      {
        value: 1548,
        name: 'e'
      }
    ]
  }]
};


myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/3.7.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 400px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes but i need to use my custom html, i have hidden the default legend

Comment: I don't think you can dispatch these events on custom legends. These events works only with echarts js legends.
Now the only workaround is to write your own click listener on legends and filter data at your end.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I have stumbled upon the same problem recently and I have found an answer.

I will leave it here, in case someone will need it.

I used the API of echarts, namely `legendToggleSelect` action:

```js
dispatchAction({
    type: 'legendToggleSelect',
    name: string // the name of the series you want to toggle
})
```

More details here:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.legend.legendToggleSelect

You can also hide the default legend (add to the option list `legend: {show: false},`)